# Get max N numbers in an array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I want to know is there any easy to get the N max/min number with Javascript.

For example:

> Give [3,9,8,1,2,6,8]

Want the Max 3 elements

```
Will return [9,8,8]
```

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on what sort of strategy you could use, or do you know of any functions that could be useful? I’ll give you a hint: everything you need is on `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this,

```
var numbers = [3,9,8,1,2,6,8].

numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}).slice(-3); // returns [8, 8, 9]
```

More info on Array.sort here, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: That’s a lexical sort, and it’d probably be better to use “slice”.

Comment: In this case for example 40 is smaller than 5, so it should work

Comment: @ArtemPetrosian: How do you know what this case is?

Comment: @minitech I mean that by default sort() order is according to string Unicode code points.

Comment: How about a solution that doesn't sort the entire array? One that uses built in function and/or something from lodash would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to sort array and than get 3 last or first numbers

```
// initial array
var a = [ 5, 2, 6, 10, 2 ];

// you need custom function because by default sort() is alphabetic 
a.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b; });

// smallest numbers
console.log(a.slice(0,3));

// biggest numbers
console.log(a.slice(-3));
```

Comment: That removes the smallest three numbers from the array.